# Matplotlib gif - xticks stay between frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

I have produced a gif of some data using the gif package. This was working yesterday, so I'm not quite sure what I've changed, but now when I produce the .gif it is transparent background and the xticks/yticks don't seem to change between frames - they just stay and grow every frame, eventually causing the x-axis (here my ylim is fixed) to become completely black. Do you know what could possibly be causing this strange interaction?

Code:

```
@gif.frame
def lookForward(X1,y1,test1,Pred1,std1):
    
#     Input:
#         X1 - input data timestamps
#         y1 - input measurements
#         test1 - timestamps of outputs
#         tidePred1 - estimates of sensor measurements generated from GP posterior mean
#         std1 - standard deviation of posterior prediction
#
#     Output:
#         None
#       
#   
#     This function plots the posterior mean in blue, and the measurements it was based on in red. It plots one
#     and two standard deviations from the posterior mean in darkening shades of blue.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))
    fig.clf()

    ax.scatter(X1, y1, label="Observations",s=8,color='red')
    ax.plot(test1, Pred1, label="Posterior Mean Function",color='blue')
    ax.fill_between(
        test1,
        Pred1 - 1.96 * std1,
        Pred1 + 1.96 * std1,
        alpha=0.4,
        label=r"95% Confidence Interval",
        color = 'blue'
    )

    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
    ax.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(),fontsize=20,loc=1)

    ax.set(xlabel="time (measurements)",ylabel=dataTitle+' ' +unit, 
           title="Sequential look forward prediction (lookahead = " +str(lookahead)+" measurements)",
           ylim = [min(t.true)-1,max(t.true)+1])
```

```
#     Use lookForward to plot all the necessary aspects of the prediction, and add each image to frames
    frames.append(lookForward(train,ploty,test,Pred,std))
    

# Save a gif, titled 'SequentialPredictionXMeasure.gif' (where X is the lookahead and Measure is the desired
# measurement), with 100ms between each frame.
gif.save(frames, "SequentialPrediction"+str(lookahead)+measurement+".gif", 
     duration=100, 
     )
```

(Note frames is produces within a for loop.

An example of the gif that is being produced is shown below:
[image: This gif has the x ticks growing over the duration of the gif, such that every previous xtick is included in the current frame.]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering, I solved it! If anyone uses the gif package, there seems to be some interaction (please someone else tell me if this is incorrect) between gif.frame and the plt.subplots, where the figure patch was transparent. Then, when making the gif, each frame is just overlayed on each other, causing the issue.

The solution was to set the figure to white:

```
f.patch.set_facecolor('white')
f.patch.set_alpha(1)
```